Why build a sturdy embankment at the end of a runway if there isn't much to protect beyond it?
I read on the Wikipedia page about the Jeju Air Flight 2216 crash today:

The aircraft overshot the runway and struck an embankment holding the ILS array while attempting a belly landing after its front landing gear failed to deploy at Muan International Airport

What's the point of making that embankment so sturdy? The plane was landing fine (source) before it hits the embankment and on Google Maps I don't see much to protect behind aside maybe a few unlucky cars.

Source: Google Street.
More generally, why add a sturdy embankment at the end of a runway if there's not much to protect behind?

Overview of the end of the runway:

Image source: Sky News on YouTube.

This thread is approaching the point of speculating about an accident, and has been locked to avoid further devolution in that direction.

This answer is an attempt to gather facts and references to inform on ICAO standards and how they might be applicable to the context. Elements might be wrong or incomplete, and cannot be used to draw any conclusion. Drawing conclusions is the mission given to the ARAIB investigation team, it will take months to collect facts and conclude.

Accident circumstances
The aircraft landed on RWY 19, following a southward course. From ASN:

Jeju Air Flight JC2216, a Boeing 737-800 registered HL8088, was involved in an accident at Muan International Airport (MWX/RKJB), South Korea. The aircraft made a gear-up landing on runway 19. It slid pas the end of the runway and collided with the ILS localizer antenna array and a wall. [...] MWX runway 19 has a Landing Distance Available (LDA) of 2800 m.

From the airport instrument procedures, the runway and the location of the south berm supporting the localizer antennas:

Localizer berm
The IMAN localizer, used for a precision approach of category I, is located south of RWY 19 beyond the runway end. The antennas are placed on top of a berm. From Google Street View, berm seen from the west side:


ICAO standards
ICAO is a UN agency for the facilitation of international aviation. Almost all countries have signed the Chicago Convention and are part of ICAO.
ICAO States members design, publish and update common standards and recommendations, in the form of Annexes to the Convention. Annexes referenced in the answer are mostly Annex 10 (navigational aids) and 14 (airports). Korea uses ICAO standards for its international airports. You can read more in:

Do all International airports need to be certified by ICAO?

Standards applicable to localizer support

Why adding a sturdy embankment at the end of a runway if there's not much to protect behind?

The embankment isn't for protection. The south end of the landing strip is about 6 m below the north end. The berm is to raise the localizer array.

Source (modified).
This additional height was likely necessary to meet the beam requirements in Annex 10 (e.g. range and phase linearity).
A similar accident occurred in 2004, at Halifax in Canada: An overloaded freighter, a Boeing 747-244SF, missed its takeoff and hit an earthen berm supporting the localizer array (investigation report).
ICAO defines a runway end safety area (RESA), which must be as extended as possible, with a minimum required of 90 m from the runway strip.
In the Halifax accident, the investigation team determined the berm wasn't part of the RESA and thus was allowed. The investigators noted there were similar berms at different airports in Canada.
In 2013 Korea proposed to extend the RESA from 90 m to 240 m for long runways. The most recent edition of Annex 14 publicly accessible is dated 2022. It includes a recommendation (not a standard):

3.5.4 Recommendation.— A runway end safety area should, as far as practicable, extend from the end of a runway strip to a distance of at least: 240 m where the code number is 3 or 4 [...].

At Muan, the runway has a code number 4 (minimum takeoff distance 1,800 m and over).
Current frangibility requirements for obstacles
Frangibility requirements extend past the RESA 90 m, in particular for navigation equipment like a localizer. In 2022 edition of ICAO Annex 14, the reference for aerodrome design:

9.9.5 Any equipment or installation required for air navigation or for aircraft safety purposes which must be located on or near a strip of a precision approach runway category I, II or III and which: a) is situated within 240 m from the end of the strip [...] shall be frangible and mounted as low as possible.

Doc 9157 Aerodrome Design Manual, Part 6, Frangibility (2006), which is a technical manual detailing Annex 14 specifications, mentions about the previous specification:

1.3.4 Annex 14, Volume I, Chapter 9, also specifies that any equipment or installation required for air navigation purposes which must be located on or near a strip of a precision approach runway category I, II or III and which: a) is situated within 240 m from the end of the strip and [...] should be frangible and mounted as low as possible.

Note one document uses must, the other should. It can be an indication this specification has changed from a recommendation in 2006 to a standard in 2022. Another possibility is this matter is more complex than I can see, and my view is actually incomplete. In addition, nothing indicates airports must be partially redesigned when the standards change.
Definition of the runway strip (Annex 14):

3.4.2 A strip shall extend before the threshold and beyond the end of the runway or stopway for a distance of at least: [...] 60 m.

A stopway is an area which can be used in case of overrun after landing or aborted takeoff. The existing area on each end of Muan runway is not a stopway, it's a clearway, an obstacle-free area for the safety of the takeoff. In this case, the runway strip extends 60 m beyond the threshold. The strip is depicted as a dotted rectangle on the airport diagram.
The frangibility is thus recommended (or required, as explained above) on a distance of 60+240 = 300 m beyond the threshold.
Muan runway strip at the south, with corresponding distances (magenta line is 300 m long):

Source: Google Satellite XYZ tile server (modified), distances are ellipsoidal (EPSG:3857).
The distance of 240 m extends past the localizer. This tends to indicate the localizer should be concerned by the frangibility specification. However remember we don't know if the applicable items are recommendations or standards. I'm personally doubtful Korean engineers and the certification team would have made a mistake when assessing this aspect, so don't draw hasty conclusions.
Runway excursion events
Regardless of whether the berm at Muan was compliant with applicable ICAO standards, the question about whether it should be allowed by ICAO standards is legitimate, but the answer is not straightforward, some food for thought:

Regulations cannot be based on very rare events, even catastrophic, that's not specific to aviation. Neither carriers nor travelers are able to pay for "total" safety, flying is inherently hazardous. Compromises must be found when agreeing on airport design specifications at worldwide level.

Specifications are adjusted, sometimes changed in depth after incidents and accidents. Investigation reports always draw lessons from what happened, to ensure what was supposed to be rare isn't actually more frequent than initially evaluated.

Statistics are gathered by different organizations. E.g. we know there are about 10 runway excursion events a year worldwide for commercial aircraft. This is the second cause of all accidents.

IATA, the syndicate for commercial carriers, publishes an annual detailed report on safety, with an analysis of the factors contributing to accidents. One of their standard cause is Inadequate overrun area, trench, ditch, proximity of structures.

From a IATA report for 2015 accidents (I've no access to a more recent one), there has been 68 accidents worldwide. Inadequate overrun area, trench, ditch, proximity of structures was a contributing factor for only 2% of the accidents, this was the least contributing factor to accidents. If a localizer was involved, it would have been in this class of contributing factors.


Localizer at ground level
For comparison a regular localizer array at ground level (source):

References

Muan Airport diagram.
All ICAO Annexes
ICAO Annex 10 volume I (navaids, pdf)
ICAO Annex 13 (accident investigation, pdf), used for ARAIB.
ICAO Annex 14 volume I (aerodromes, pdf)
ICAO Documents associated with Annex 14.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In this particular case, the embankment wasn't built to protect anything, only to raise the ILS array so that it can function.
Generally, airport walls and embankments are not built to protect something behind them, but primarily to protect the aircraft. You wouldn't want cars, people, animals, or anything else from the outside to randomly venture onto the runway.
And for an aircraft that has overrun the runway, it's sometimes safer to crash into a barrier than to keep going past it - same principle as traffic barriers. It's not always safer, it's not always a good decision, but it's not without rationale.
Muan airport (MWX) in particular has public roads followed by water on both ends of its runway. It's not great placement for an airport safety-wise; ideally, you'd want flat empty plains on both ends. But safety in the event of a crash is rarely among the top concerns when picking the spot for a new airport, especially in space-restricted countries such as Korea. It's mitigated after the placement is decided upon.
Seawater generally isn't considered a safe surface - it can be better than hard surface in some crashes, particularly belly landings, but greatly complicates any emergency assistance. So, overall, one wouldn't deliberately design an airport for runway overrun to go into the ocean, even if it often ends up being the case. In this case, raised ILS placement was a technical requirement, and since the terrain past the runway is dangerous anyway, it likely wasn't considered a big safety compromise.
It's possible to make runway overrun incidents safer. ICAO recommends extending runway safety areas as far as practicable. EMAS or Engineering Material Arresting System - basically, a bed of foamed concrete - is a major improvement, helping with malfunctioning brakes and wheels-up landings. It's mandatory when a minimum runway safety area cannot be provided, but not otherwise, though studies show that EMAS have globally saved more money than they have cost to build.
In Muan's case, the runway safety area complies with the 300 ft minimum, but not with the preferred 1,000. The line of thinking that drives such decisions is that you keep the RSA safe, and if it's not enough, it's too late. But there's a lot of airports with unsafe overrun areas around the world. It can be buildings, highways, cliff dropoffs. MWX is not the worst. Minimalist airport design with water on one end and buildings on the other is pretty common in coastal areas.
In hindsight, it was a bad decision to build the ILS localizer on a raised embankment, rather than level the ground more smoothly or design a taller collapsible metal structure for it. But it's not exceptional; past the RSA, all bets are off. A number of planes have crashed into airport buildings after a failed takeoff or landing, which could have been avoided, had these buildings been built off-axis from the runway.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

According to two experts on Sky News in 2 independent interviews, there shouldn't be a sturdy embankment at the end of a runway.




You would not normally have a heavy duty concrete wall in the overrun area at the end of the runway.

(Name of the expert in this interview:
Former airline pilot Terry Tozer http://www.terrytozer.co.uk/)




That kind of structure [the embarkment] shouldn't be there.

(Name of the expert in this interview:
David Learmount https://davidlearmount.com/about/)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
